# AngularJS event after placeholders evaluated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with placeholders in the template ( {{ }} ).. And I need to fire a function after the placeholders are evaluated.. 
Is there any way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: In short - no - at least not without ugly hacks. What are you trying to do - functionally speaking?

Comment: Wouldn't $eval work for that? @pkozlowski.opensource

Comment: @finishingmove I understood the question as: "how can I execute a JavaScript function after AngularJS interpolation directive finished its work". Might be interpreting it badly and this is why I wanted to learn more about the functional use case.

Comment: @finishingmove Yeah you can use $eval, but that isn't the same as when the content actually makes it into the DOM, at which point you might want to get calculated widths and heights of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it like this:

```
scope.$watch('binded_var', function(){
            // Do stuff here
        });
```